# How to apply Field filter in Quarkus Rest API

Tags: java, quarkus

I am using Quarkus Rest API and my resource has lots of fields. I want to support fields in query parameter so that my response can contain only those fields mentioned in the client request, Does quarkus has in built support for fields parameter? How to implement it?

For example my resource is Person, it has id, name, address, phoneNumber, department etc.

My rest api should support

1. /persons? :
   response should be [{"name":"abc","id":1,"address":"myaddress","phoneNumber":"32423423",....},{..}]
2. /person?fields=name,phoneNumber
   response should be [{"name":"abc","phoneNumber":"32423423"},{..}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quarkus does not have any built in support for automatically creating a projection of the result based on query params - you would have to implement that yourself.

You can however open an issue on our GitHub requesting this feature